# bind a dictionary from object from observablecollection of object to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

i have a observablecollection of objects, each object has some variables and a dictionary,
how can i bind the key's of the dictionary to a datagrid

c#

```
        public ObservableCollection<Printer> PrinterList
        {
            get { return _PrinterList; }
            set
            {
                _PrinterList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PrinterList));
            }
        }

    public class Printer
    {
        public string Hostname { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string,string> resultList;
        public Printer()
        {
            resultList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

    }
```

i would like to display a datagrid like this

```
Hostname    |   key     |   key
printer1    |   value   |   value
printer2    |   value   |   value
printer3    |   value   |   value
```

so i think i need to bind the dictionary from each object to a datagrid thats inside a datagrid thats bind to the observablecollection.

am i wrong in thinking i should do it like that? or is there a better way to display this kind of data?

thnx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to bind to an `ObservableCollection<Printer>`, you should create a `PrinterViewModel` class that has a scalar property for each column that you intend to display in the `DataGrid`:

```
public class PrinterViewModel
{
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

> i would like to display a datagrid like this ...

You will then need to transform your source collection into something that the `DataGrid` can work with, i.e. an `ObservableCollection<PrinterViewModel>`:

```
var sourceCollection = new ObservableCollection<PrinterViewModel>();
foreach (var printer in _PrinterList)
{
    if (printer.resultList != null)
    {
        foreach (var result in printer.resultList)
        {
            sourceCollection.Add(new PrinterViewModel()
            {
                Hostname = printer.Hostname,
                Key = result.Key,
                Value = result.Value
            });
        }
    }
}
```